# Anyone using Laravel with Facebook Messenger platform api?

Tags: facebook, laravel, messenger

Anyone using Laravel framework? Need some help
I am developing Messenger Chat bot on Laravel I have set up everything such as Route,Webhook and also subscribed page but no respond from messenger chat..
Any idea?
ps. It's working without Laravel

Comment: Do you set webhook url in `VerifyCsrfToken` for excluded from CSRF verification?

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide the laravel log file. 
Also you can check class `VerifyCsrf` and add webhook URL to disabled routed array:

```
protected $routes = [
        'webhook/facebook/url/paste/here',
        'another/route/here',
];
```